# Python pipeline to Mayavi

Tags: python, mayavi

I'm trying to write a program in Python that needs to 'talk' to Mayavi (to check the zoom level, for example) and then consequently operate on the data in some way, then re check a parameter etc. I can do this with C and Gnuplot using piplines between C and gnuplot... but after reading the Mayavi documentation, I can't seem to find a similar thing for a python code (there are instructions for ipython, but I'm writing a full code).

How does one open a pipeline to Mayavi so that Python can access Mayavi's object attributes and vice-versa?

Answer (score 2):

Mayavi does not expose control to other processes using pipes (terminology note: "pipes" not "pipelines"). If you wish to write a Python program that uses Mayavi for visualization, just [use it as a library](https://github.com/enthought/mayavi/blob/master/examples/mayavi/standalone.py). The ["IPython" instructions](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html) that you refer to are also valid for use inside of a full-fledged program.

Comment: I only require Mayavi's mlab module to do some 3D plotting, so do I still have to go through the process of importing the engine etc like in the page you linked? But I'll check and see if the ipython instructions do what I'd like to do anyway. Thanks!